# need some space between 2 tabs in a magento site

Tags: css

under banners you can see " new products" , "featured products", "best seller" , "on sale" products.

betweeen new products" &  "featured products" ,

I want to add space between "new arrivals" and "featured products" as in

I want to display some space.

please help me to style between those 2 tabs.

let me know if you need any clarifications.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide some code that demonstrates what you've tried and a brief explanation of the issue you're trying to work through.

Comment: A screenshot is no good. We need to see the code. Need to know the name of the elements that require css.

Comment: Also, are you using `jquery/jquery UI`?

Comment: yes, it uses some js files, but can't we find solution using inspeact element?

Comment: You have removed the screen shot (and reference to the URL) and didn't provide any code - can you see how the question is now without any context and totally useless to other users looking for similar answers? You really should add some code and/or a Fiddle (or similar) that demonstrates your issue, for others to find this question useful. That is how/why SO works for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you really should add some code to your question so that other users can see what you've tried and help you iron out the bugs; that being said - the URL is in the screenshot ...

Add this to your CSS:

```
.ui-slider-tabs-list li.selected {
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

That will add space between the selected element and the next.

You will need to add margin to both sides for tabs that are not first in line, like so ...

```
.ui-slider-tabs-list li + li.selected {
    margin-left: 2px;
}
```

... this way you add space on both sides if the `.selected` list item is preceded by another list item.

Comment: How do you know the class names without a single line of code in the question?

Comment: You paid more attention to the image than what I did :P

Comment: I wanted to tell you "because I'm psychic" :D